# Remove substring and all characters before from pyspark column

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark object column in a dataframe (df) like this:

```
|      'A'              |
-------------------------
| field 1 - order - one |
| field 2 - sell        |
|     order             |
|     sell              |
```

I'd like to remove the first occurence of '-  ' and all characters before using regex_replace or whatever other sql function that would work in this case but having a little trouble. Below is the desired output:

```
|      'A'        |
-------------------
|   order - one   |
|     sell        |
|     order       |
|     sell        |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("field 1 - order", "None"),
        ("field 2 - sell", "None"),
        ("order", "None"),
        ("sell", "None"),
    ],
    ["A", "B"],
)
df.show()

df = (
    df
    .withColumn("A", F.regexp_replace("A" , "^([^-]+)-" ,"",)  )
)

df.show()
```

outputs:

```
+---------------+----+
|              A|   B|
+---------------+----+
|field 1 - order|None|
| field 2 - sell|None|
|          order|None|
|           sell|None|
+---------------+----+

+------+----+
|     A|   B|
+------+----+
| order|None|
|  sell|None|
| order|None|
|  sell|None|
+------+----+
```

Comment: Nice... what if I had 2 '-' and just wanted to split on the first occurrence?

Comment: @chicagobeast12 updated the expression. this should work..please add all requirements in original post to prevent scope creep

Answer (score 0):

Another way out is to split column A by the character and slice the resulting array and get the element. Code below

```
df.withColumn('A', slice(split('A','\-'),-1,1)[0]).show()
```